# Veraltete Vergangenheitsform

Tags: conjugation

Ich habe beim Lesen alter Texte schon mehrmals diese Satzbildung getroffen:

> Deine Zauber binden wieder, was die Mode streng geteilt.

Mir würde Folgendes natürlicher klingen:

> Deine Zauber binden wieder, was die Mode streng geteilt **hat**.

Bildete sich damals die Vergangenheit nur mithilfe des Partizipes II, und ohne konjugiertes Verb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das ist aus der *Ode an die Freude* von Friedrich Schiller, die von Ludwig van Beethoven in seiner neunten Symphonie vertont wurde. Schiller hat diesen Text im Jahr 1785 geschrieben, und der entsprechende Abschnitt lautet im Original (Rechtschreibung wie im Original):

> Deine Zauber binden wieder,
>   was der Mode Schwerd getheilt;
>   Bettler werden Fürstenbrüder,
>   wo dein sanfter Flügel weilt.

Beethoven hatte schon lange vor, dieses Gedicht zu vertonen. Er begann an der Arbeit zu neunten Symphonie im Jahr 1815, uraufgeführt wurde sie erst 1824.

Beethoven hat diesen Abschnitt wie folgt geändert (moderne Rechtschreibung):

> Deine Zauber binden wieder
>   was die Mode streng geteilt;
>   Alle Menschen werden Brüder,
>   wo dein sanfter Flügel weilt.

Ein Hilfsverb hätte daher schon wegen des Reims keinen Platz. Für das Fehlen des Hilfsverbs gibt es aber einen viel gewichtigeren Grund, der mit dem Reim gar nichts zu tun hat:

Vor 200 Jahren waren in der gehobenen Sprache solche Hilfsverben nicht üblich.

Wer Texte von Zeitgenossen Schillers liest (z.B. Goethe, E.T.A. Hoffmann, Immanuel Kant, Georg Wilhelm Friedrich Hegel, ...) wird immer wieder auf Sätze stoßen, bei denen das Hilfsverb, das wir am Ende eines Satzes erwarten, fehlt.